# Building MSVC project with cmake and command-line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, build, cmake

Good day!

Let us have a source file `main.cpp` and a `CMakeLists.txt` file containing the next text:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(tmp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
add_executable(tmp.elf main.cpp)
```

Let's say the `main.cpp` file contains a simple "Hello, World!" program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

We can build the project with `cmake CMakeLists.txt && make`. Then we'll just get the `tmp.elf` file which we can just run. Or we can get no `tmp.elf` file and assume that something is wrong with the `main.cpp` source file (assuming the compiler and cmake are installed properly on the building system).

**So, the question is:** how can we do the same on the Windows machine? E.g. we will get the `tmp.vcproj` file after running `cmake CMakeLists.txt` and then we need to build it somehow. How the build process can be performed using command-line? *(Java's Process.start(), actually :-P )*

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can start the build in a platform and CMake generator independent fashion by invoking cmake with the `--build` option:

```
cmake --build .
```

For multi-configuration generators, you can specify the configuration in the following way:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Also see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode).

Comment: Yeah, it worked: `cmake CMakeLists.txt -G "Visual Studio 9 2008"` and then - `cmake --build .`. Thanks! =)

Comment: @GameDeveloper It worked for visual studio 11, please submit a bug in [cmake site](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues).